# \LTleft, \LTright, and \scriptsize not working with revtex4

Tags: spacing, margins, longtable, fontsize, revtex

I have the follwing table:

```
   \documentclass[a4paper,preprint,aps,
                   unsortedaddress]{revtex4}
    \usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,
                left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{longtable,array,booktabs}

    \ifdefined\mc
       \renewcommand{\mc}{\multicolumn}
    \else
       \newcommand{\mc}{\multicolumn}
    \fi

    \begin{document} 

        \setlength\LTleft{-3.0cm}
        \setlength\LTright{-2.0cm}

        \scriptsize

    \begin{longtable}{ l r @{--} p{1.3cm} >{\centering}p{2.6cm} 
                       *{5}{p{1.25cm}} p{2.1cm} p{0.7cm} }               
    %% headers and footers

    \caption{Table} \\ 
    \hline\hline
    \endfirsthead

    \mc{10}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \emph{Continued from previous page}} \\ 
    \hline
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & \mc{2}{c}{bbb--ccc} & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii & jjj \\
    \hline
    \endhead

    \hline
    \mc{10}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}} \\
    \endfoot

    \hline\hline
    \endlastfoot

    %% body of table

        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & \mc{2}{c}{bbb--ccc} & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii & jjj \\
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii & jjj \\
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii & jjj \\
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii & jjj \\

    \end{longtable}
    \end{document}
```

around which I would like to reduce the left and right margin to 0.5 cm using `\setlength\LTleft{-3.0cm}` and `\setlength\LTright{-2.0cm}`. Furthermore, I have to apply `\scriptsize` for the table. However, none of these commands are working with `revtex4`. Could you please provide a solution to this problem?

Comment: it's unrelated to revtex, you have set impossible constraints, you have removed the stretch from LTleft and LTright, and there is no stretch glue in the table so the table has a fixed width and there is no flexibility to make a row \textwidth wide.  How to you want tex to adjust things?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts