# Use \scriptsize and shift a longtable to the left with revtex4

Tags: spacing, margins, longtable, fontsize, revtex

I have the following table:

```
   \documentclass[a4paper,preprint,aps,
                   unsortedaddress]{revtex4}
    \usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,
                left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{longtable,array,booktabs}

    \ifdefined\mc
       \renewcommand{\mc}{\multicolumn}
    \else
       \newcommand{\mc}{\multicolumn}
    \fi

    \begin{document} 

        \setlength\LTleft{-3.0cm}
        \setlength\LTright{-2.0cm}

        \scriptsize

    \begin{longtable}{ l r @{--} p{1.3cm} >{\centering}p{2.6cm} 
                       *{4}{p{1.25cm}} p{2.1cm}}               
    %% headers and footers

    \caption{Table} \\ 
    \hline\hline
    \endfirsthead

    \mc{9}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \emph{Continued from previous page}} \\ 
    \hline
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & \mc{2}{c}{bbb--ccc} & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii \\
    \hline
    \endhead

    \hline
    \mc{9}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}} \\
    \endfoot

    \hline\hline
    \endlastfoot

    %% body of table

        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & \mc{2}{c}{bbb--ccc} & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii \\
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii \\
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii \\
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii \\

    \end{longtable}
    \end{document}
```

which I would like to shift to the left by setting `\setlength\LTleft{-3.0cm}` 
and `\setlength\LTright{-2.0cm}`. Furthermore, I have to apply `\scriptsize` for the table. However, none of these commands are working with `revtex4`. Could you please provide a solution to this problem? (This question is the same as in [\LTleft, \LTright, and \scriptsize not working with revtex4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474569/ltleft-ltright-and-scriptsize-not-working-with-revtex4), but I cannot sign up with that username.) 
If it is not possible, an alternative solution would also be useful for me. For this case, I attached the first page of my real table.

[image]

Comment: this is the same question as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474569/ltleft-ltright-and-scriptsize-not-working-with-revtex4 are you the same user? You could get the accounts merged

Comment: How to perform this?

Comment: delete `\setlength\LTright{-2.0cm}` and just set LTleft and the table will move left

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain why `\scriptsize` does not work?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: scriptsize does work, try without it and the fonts would be bigger

Comment: Sorry, but it seems to me that removing `\setlength\LTright{-2.0cm}` does not solve the problem of shifting the table to the left by 3.0 cm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89657/discussion-between-tobir-and-david-carlisle).

Answer (score 1):

The `revtex4` classes (by the way, the current version is `revtex4-2`) issue `\table@hook` when a `longtable` is being built. The standard value for `\table@hook` is `\small`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,preprint,aps,unsortedaddress]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{longtable,array,booktabs}

\newcommand{\mc}{\multicolumn}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{xlongtable}[1]
 {\appdef\table@hook{#1}\longtable}
 {\endlongtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{xlongtable}{\scriptsize}{
  l r @{--} p{1.3cm} >{\centering}p{2.6cm} 
  *{4}{p{1.25cm}} p{2.1cm}
}
%% headers and footers

\caption{Table} \\
\toprule
\endfirsthead

\mc{9}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \emph{Continued from previous page}} \\ 
\midrule
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & \mc{2}{c}{bbb--ccc} & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii \\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\mc{9}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

%% body of table

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & \mc{2}{c}{bbb--ccc} & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii \\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii \\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii \\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii \\

\end{xlongtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I removed the conditional redefinition of `\mc`: if the command is defined, it would be a mistake to redefine it without knowing where it comes from.

Setting `\LTleft` and `\LTright` requires a hack. Be aware that such tricks can be worthy a rejection, as they change the shape of documents from what `revtex` people expect.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,preprint,aps,unsortedaddress]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{longtable,array,booktabs}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\mc}{\multicolumn}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{xlongtable}[1]
 {\appdef\table@hook{#1}\longtable}
 {\endlongtable}
\newcommand\tobirgobblefour[4]{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{xlongtable}{%
  \scriptsize % this table is in script size
  \setlength{\LTleft}{-3cm plus 1fill}% move to left
  \tobirgobblefour % remove the setting of \LTleft and \LTright
}{
  l r @{--} p{1.3cm} >{\centering}p{2.6cm} 
  *{4}{p{1.25cm}} p{2.1cm}
}
%% headers and footers

\caption{Table} \\
\toprule
\endfirsthead

\mc{9}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \emph{Continued from previous page}} \\ 
\midrule
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & \mc{2}{c}{bbb--ccc} & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii \\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\mc{9}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

%% body of table
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & \mc{2}{c}{bbb--ccc} & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii \\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii \\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii \\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii \\

\end{xlongtable}

\end{document}
```

Here I used `showframe` just to make the page boundaries clear.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I still have a problem with shifting the table to the left with -3.0 cm. Could you please help me how to perform it?

Comment: @TobiR I provided it. However, you shouldn't be doing such tricks, as your paper might be rejected. If it is not for a submission to PhysRev (or associated journal), then don't use `revtex4` to begin with.